# Login do Facebook com Ionic/AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, apache-cordova, ionic

Estou tentando fazer login do facebook com Ionic/AngularJS.

Sempre que tento realizar o login retorna este erro:

> Object {errorMessage: "User cancelled dialog", errorCode: "4201"}

Estou seguindo esse exemplo: [Login Facebook com Ionic](https://ionicthemes.com/tutorials/about/native-facebook-login-with-ionic-framework)

Como resolver esse problema ?

```
var app = angular.module("starter");

app.controller("MainCtrl", function($scope, $state, $ionicHistory, $ionicLoading){

  // This is the success callback from the login method
  var fbLoginSuccess = function(response) {
    console.log("cliquei");
    if (!response.authResponse){
      fbLoginError("Cannot find the authResponse");
      return;
    }

    var authResponse = response.authResponse;

    getFacebookProfileInfo(authResponse)
      .then(function(profileInfo) {
      console.log("Email profile " + profileInfo.email);      
      $ionicLoading.hide();      
    }, function(fail){
      // Fail get profile info
      console.log('profile info fail', fail);
    });
  };

  // This is the fail callback from the login method
  var fbLoginError = function(error){
    console.log('fbLoginError ', error);
    $ionicLoading.hide();
  };

  // This method is to get the user profile info from the facebook api
  var getFacebookProfileInfo = function (authResponse) {
    var info = $q.defer();

    facebookConnectPlugin.api('/me?fields=email,name&access_token=' + authResponse.accessToken, null,
      function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        info.resolve(response);
      },
      function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        info.reject(response);
      }
    );
    return info.promise;
  };
});
```

Comment: Cadê o código ?

Comment: @devgaspa mals ! postei o codigo.

Comment: Qual versão do Ionic/AngularJS você esta usando ?

Comment: ionic 1.1.1 e angular 1.4.7.

Comment: Certeza? você conferiu no script ionic-bundle a versão? As vezes, quando se instala via npm ocorre de vir versões anteriores. E acredito que esse erro esteja acontecendo por este motivo.

Comment: conferi sim @devgaspa o ionic eh 1.1.1 e o angular 1.4.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resolvido. Depois de muito pesquisasr acabei usando o `ngOpenFB`

https://github.com/r-wettstaedt/ngOpenFB

https://github.com/ccoenraets/OpenFB

https://ccoenraets.github.io/ionic-tutorial/ionic-facebook-integration.html